# Flask WTForms how to prevent duplicate form submission

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm new to Flask.

Forms.py:

```
class NoteForm(FlaskForm):
    note = fields.TextAreaField("Note")
    add_note = fields.SubmitField("Add Note")
```

router.py:

```
add_note_form = forms.NoteForm()
```

template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ add_note_form.add_note}}
</div>
```

Now if I click the add note button multiple times in a very short time ,the form will be summitted for multiple times, especial when the page is loading slowly.

Is there anyway I can prevent duplicate  form submission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to disable the submit button after form is submitted

```
onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Saving…'; "
```

Another way would be to give you record an id and check for duplicate in the backend.